# How to get a list of ports listening in a Fortigate firewall?

Tags: fortigate, fortinet

Since several services can be offered by the Fortigate itself (SSH and web access for admin tasks, SSL VPN, IPSec VPN...) I would like to check at a glance all ports where any service is being offered by a given unit.

Is it possible to get a list of all listening ports in a Fortigate firewall, either via CLI or Web Interface? Im looking for something similar to the output of `netstat -l` in Unix/Linux.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

Try with:

```
diagnose sys tcpsock | grep 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I think this command does provide the information I am looking for. Do you have documentation on how to read its output? I have run several searches looking for such a document but couldn´t find it

Comment: I'm sorry but this is an undocumented command and its output lacks many details ( for instance you must guess if transport protocol is TCP or UDP ).
I would recommend you to drop a request to the Fortigate TAC and cross your fingers for a clever answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since newer FortiOS versions have been released, there is also a way to view open ports on the Web Interface:

1. Activate the Local In Policy view via *System > Config > Features*, Toggle on *Local In Policy* in the Show More menu.
2. Go to *Policy & Objects > Local In*  and there you have a overview of the active listening ports.

Answer (score 1):

[Ports used by Fortinet](http://docs.fortinet.com/uploaded/files/1880/FortinetOpenPorts.pdf) was released May 9, 2014

```
Destination • Port Protocol(s) • Application(s) • Function(s)


21 TCP FTP • Log and Report uploads from FortiAnalyzer
• Anti-defacement backup and restoration (FTP). Listening on
FortiWeb
• FTP configuration backup from FortiWeb to other device
22 TCP SSH • SSH Command line based management:
• From Admin Workstation to Fortinet Device
22 TCP FTP over SSH • Log and Report uploads:
• To and from FortiCloud
• To and from FortiAnalyzer
• Anti-defacement backup and restoration (SSH/SCP) from FortiWeb
to other device
• SFTP configuration backup from FortiWeb to other device
23 TCP Telnet • Telnet Command line based management from Admin Workstation
to Fortinet devices
• HA (FGCP) between HA FortiGates
25 TCP SMTP • Alert Emails
• From FortiAnalyzer to SMTP Mail Server
• From FortiGate to SMTP Mail Server
• From FortiWeb to SMTP Mail Server
• Encrypted Virus Samples auto submitted to FortiGuard
49 TCP TACACS+ • TACACS+ from FortiAnalyzer
53 UDP DNS • DNS Lookups
• To DNS Servers
• To FortiGuard
4
4
53 UDP Fortinet Queries • FortiGuard Server List requests to FortiGuard
• AntiSpam or Web Filtering rating lookup queries to FortiGuard
• URL/AS rating lookup queries to FortiGuard
• Real-time Black List(RBL) lookup requests to RBL services
67 UDP DHCP • DHCP to and from FortiGate
68 UDP DHCP Relay • DHCP Relay to and from FortiGate
69 UDP TFTP • TFTP for backups, restoration, and firmware updates from FortiWeb
to other device
80 TCP • Default unsecure Web-based Management of Fortinet Device
• Admin Workstation to FortiAnalyzer
• Admin Workstation to FortiAuthenticator
• Admin Workstation to FortiGate
• Admin Workstation to FortiManager
• Admin Workstation to FortiWeb
80 TCP HTTP • Proxied HTTP traffic from FortiGate
80 TCP HTTP • Fortinet Device Registration to FortiGuard
• AV update requests from FortiClient to FortiManager
• Server health checks from FortiWeb to other device
• Predefined HTTP service. Only occurs if the service is used by a
policy, listening on FortiWeb
80 TCP Simple Certificate Enrollment
Protocol (SCEP)
• Issuing and revocation of digital certificates
• Listening on FortiAuthenticator
88 TCP Kerboros • Account Authentication traffic from FortiAuthenticator to Active
Directory Controllers
123 UDP NTP • Time Synchronization from Fortinet Device to NTP Server
135 TCP Client/Server (WMI, SEL) • FortiAuthenticator to Active Directory Controllers
137 UDP • Win Share to and from FortiAnalyzer (Not supported in FAZ v5.0/5.2)
• Anti-defacement backup and restoration (Windows-style share) from
FortiWeb to other device.
138 UDP • Win Share to and from FortiAnalyzer (Not supported in FAZ v5.0/5.2)
• Anti-defacement backup and restoration (Windows-style share) from
FortiWeb to other device.
5
5
139 TCP/UDP NetBIOS • Win Share to and from FortiAnalyzer (Not supported in FAZ v5.0/5.2)
• Anti-defacement backup and restoration (Windows-style share) from
FortiWeb to other device.
161 UDP Simple Network Management
Protocol (SNMP)
• SNMP Poll
• FortiManager to FortiGate
• Listening on FortiAuthenticator
• Listening on FortiWeb
162 UDP Simple Network Management
Protocol (SNMP) Traps
• To SysLog server
• To FortiAnalyzer
• To FortiManager
389 TCP/UDP LDAP • LDAP Lookups, Authentication Requests and Report queries
• PKI Authentication
• To Active Directory Domain Controllers
• To FortiAuthenticator
• To LDAP Server
443 TCP HTTPS • Default Secure Web-based Management of Fortinet Device
• Admin Workstation to Fortinet Device
• Firmware and Signature Downloads from FortiGuard
• FGD SMS to FortiGuard
• FC FTM to FortiGuard
• FC Licensing to FortiGuard
• Policy Override Auth to FortiGuard
• AntiVirus/IPS updates to FortiGuard
• URL/AS update requests to FortiGuard
• Remote Vulnerability Scan updates to FortiGuard
• Device Registration requests to FortiGuard
• Server health checks from FortiWeb to other devices
• Proxied HTTPS traffic from FortiGate to Proxy Server
• FSSO Portal and Widget traffic
6
6
443 TCP Representational state transfer
(REST) API / HTTP
• Listening on FortiAnalyzer
445 TCP Microsoft-DS Active Directory,
Windows shares
• Domain Controller Polling
• FortiAuthenticator to Active Directory Domain Controller
• Listening on FortiAnalyzer
• NTLM authentication queries.
• Anti-defacement backup and restoration (Windows-style share)
from FortiWeb to other device.
500 UDP IPsec • Secure SNMP over IPsec connection
• FortiGate to FortiAnalyzer
514 TCP/UDP Syslog messages OFTP • Device Registration
• From FortiManager to FortiAnalyzer
• From FortiGate to FortiAnalyzer
• Quarantined files to FortiAnalyzer
• Logs and Reports
• To SysLog server
• To FortiAnalyzer
• To FortiCloud
• To FortiManager
• OFTP for file submission and statistics exchange
• Between FortiGate and FortiSandbox (FortiCloud)
520 UDP Routing Information Protocol (RIP) • Listening on FortiGate
541 TCP • Device Registration • Central Management from FortiManager
• SSL Management Tunnel to FortiCloud
636 TCP Lightweight Directory Access
Protocol over TLS/SSL (LDAPS)
• Encrypted LDAP authentication traffic from
• Fortinet Devices to Active Directory Domain Controllers
• Fortinet Devices to LDAP servers (including FortiAuthenticator)
703 TCP FGCP L2 • HA Heartbeat between HA FortiGates
1000 TCP • Policy Override Keepalive listening on FortiGate
(Closed by default, but can be enabled)
7
7
1003 TCP • Policy Override Keepalive listening on FortiGate
(Closed by default, but can be enabled)
1812 TCP RADIUS • RADIUS Authentication Requests
• To FortiAuthenticator
• To RADIUS Server
1813 UDP RADIUS • RADIUS Accounting to FortiAuthenticator
2049 TCP NFS • Network File System listening on FortiAnalyzer (Not supported in
FAZ v5.0/5.2)
2302 TCP • HTTP or HTTPS administrative access to web-based manager's CLI
dashboard widget(v3.0 MR5 only)
• Listening on FortiAnalyzer
• Listening on FortiGate
2560 TCP Online Certificate Status Protocol
(OCSP)
• Obtaining the revocation status of an X.509 digital certificate,
listening on FortiAuthenticator
3000 TCP • Log aggregation listening on FortiAnalyzer
(Log aggregation server support requires model FortiAnalyzer
800 or greater)
3306 TCP • Remote MySQL database connection listening on FortiAnalyzer
3784 UDP BFD • Listening on FortiGate
4500 UDP IPsec • Secure SNMP over IPsec connection
• FortiGate to FortiAnalyzer
• FortiGate to FortiManager
5199 TCP • HA Heartbeat or synchronization listening on FortiManager
6055 UDP • HA heartbeat. Layer 2 multicast.
• From FortiWeb to other device
• Listening on FortiWeb
6056 UDP • HA configuration synchronization. Layer 2 multicast.
• From FortiWeb to other device
• Listening on FortiWeb
8
8
8000 TCP FSSO • Windows Active Directory Collector Agent for Fortinet Single Sign-On
• From Active Directory Collector to FortiGate
• From FortiAuthenticator to FortiGate
• From FortiGate to FortAuthenticator
8001 TCP SSO Mobiltity Agent • This port is used to pass userid and IP address information from
FortiClient to FortiAuthenticator.
(This functionality is not necessary for the completion of phase 1)
8002 TCP/UDP FSSO • UDP (for plain traffic), or TCP (for encrypted traffic)
• FortiAuthenticator listening for traffic - Hierarchical FSSO Info from
Tier Supplier
8003 TCP FSSO • FortiAuthenticator listening for traffic from DS/TS Agents with FSSO
Login information
8008 TCP • User authentication for policy override of HTTP traffic listening on
FortiGate
8009 TCP • FortiClient Portal listening on FortiGate 1000A, 3600A, and 5005FA2
only
8010 TCP • User authentication for policy override of HTTPS traffic from
FortiClient to FortiGate
(This port and IP address must be load balanced between all four
FortiGate 1500Ds)
8333 TCP • Configuration replication.
• From FortiWeb to other device
• Listening on FortiWeb
8888 UDP • Application and Signature updates requests, FortiGuard AntiSpam or
Web Filtering rating lookup requests and URL/AS Rating requests
• FortiClient to FortiGuard
• FortiGate to FortiGuard
• FortiClient to FortiManager
• FortiGate to FortiManager
• FortiGuard Server List
• FortiClient to FortiGuard
• FortiGate to FortiGuard
9
9
8890 TCP • A/V, IPS signature, AntiSpam and Web Filtering update requests
• FortiGate to FortiManager
• FortiManger to FortiGuard
8890 ETH Layer
2
• Between FortiGate and FortiManager for FortiGuard Updates
8900 TCP • VPN Settings distribution to authenticated FortiClient installations
• FortiClient to FortiGate
9443 UDP • AV/IPS Push
• FortiGuard to FortiGate
• FortiGuard to FortiManager
• FortiManager to FortiGate
10443 TCP • Connection to SSL-VPN Portals, listening on FortiGate
10151 TCP • Contract validation from FortiGate to FortiCloud
```

Answer (score 0):

download nmap on a linux or windows machine and `nmap $fortigateIP`

That will scan the $fortigateIP for common ports (ftp, ssh, telnet, smtp, http, pop3, imap, https, etc)

[Explanation of nmap-services (aka nmap common ports)](http://nmap.org/book/nmap-services.html)
[nmap usage doc](http://nmap.org/nmap_doc.html)

Comment: I am interested in the services listening in the outside interface. Should I scan the outside interface, the report would contain information for ports listening on the firewall itself but also for ports having a static NAT for internal network services. So, this would be confusing. That´s why I am trying to get this information directly from the firewall itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer some way to check directly on the Fortigate device which ports are listening, but I could not find yet any command to do this that is clearly documented. However, I´ve found today this document referencing which ports are used by several Fortinet devices for different functions.

http://docs.fortinet.com/uploaded/files/1880/FortinetOpenPorts.pdf